# AVAudioPlayer: MP3 file not playing on device, but works in Simulator (iOS 6)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

I'm using the code below to play a MP3 file with AVAudioPlayer on iOS 6. The file seems to be playing, but there is no sound output on the device. 
It works fine in the iOS Simulator though.

**File .h:**

```
#import "UIKit/UIKit.h"
#import "AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioPlayerDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) AVAudioPlayer *player;

@end
```

**File .m:**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize player;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"beep_7" ofType:@"mp3"];
    NSLog(@"Audio path: %@", soundFilePath);

    NSError *error;
    player =[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath] error:&error];

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error in audioPlayer: %@",[error localizedDescription]);
    } 
    else {
        [player setDelegate:self];
        [player setNumberOfLoops:3]; //just to make sure it is playing my file several times
        player.volume = 1.0f;

        if([player prepareToPlay]) //It is always ready to play
            NSLog(@"It is ready to play");
        else
            NSLog(@"It is NOT ready to play ");

        if([player play]) //It is always playing
            NSLog(@"It should be playing");
        else
            NSLog(@"An error happened");
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: If you implement the delegate method `audioPlayerDecodeErrorDidOccur:error:`, do you see any errors?

Comment: I already implemented that method, and it doesnt appear any Log...

-(void)audioPlayerDecodeErrorDidOccur: (AVAudioPlayer *)player error:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"audioPlayerDecodeErrorDidOccur -> Error in audioPlayer: %@",[error localizedDescription]);
}

Comment: You seem to be testing on the device. Does it work in the iOS Simulator?

Comment: That's true. It's working in the iOS Simulator, but not in my iPhone...what could be the problem with my iPhone?

Comment: It was a couple of mistakes I had. First of all my file was damaged and secondly, i hit my muted button off. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Done, I just forgot ;)

Comment: It's working in the iOS Simulator, but not in my iPhone...what could be the problem with my iPhone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code you've posted works fine for me.

- Are you sure you're including the beep_7.mp3 in your target?
- Are you sure the filename is correct? iOS devices use a case-sensitive filesystem!
- Are you sure your device isn't muted?
- Are you sure the file is a valid, working MP3 file?

Comment: I am testing with two different mp3 file. I have synchronised those files with my iPhone and I have played there and it worked. So, files work and my devide isn't muted.
And about if I have included those files to my target, the unique thing I have done it was to drag then to my project into the Supporting Files...am I missing something else?

Comment: I have just checked my target->Build Phases, and both files are there.

Comment: Ah, my device was in mute. Great answer covers all the problems.

Answer (score 2):

check your device's silent mode is on or off?
I once got the same problem as yours,after i changed my slient mode off,all solved!

Answer (score 0):

Did you set AudioSessionCategory?

```
{
    NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
    BOOL success = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: 
    avaudiosessioncategoryplayandrecorderror: &setCategoryError];
}
```